# Raspberry Pi program delay

Tags: raspberry-pi, delay, autostart, midori

I use Raspberry Pi to display web page automatically at startup.

The issue is : As soon as the raspberry is started, Midori is launched, but I've the message "Cannot Resolve Hostname....".

When I update the webpage 30 seconds after startup, it is correctly displayed.

How I can make a delay to launch Midori after X seconds ?

I launch my webpage with `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

Comment: You have to wait until you have obtained an ip before you launch the browser. Question with fix is shown here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79330/trying-to-open-a-browser-on-startup-on-my-raspberry-pi

Comment: I've already try, but it doesn't work...

Comment: You could try add a small delay before midori starts, which would be less reliable than ip checking. See section 3 on this link. Follow the steps and inside the bash script above the line that calls midori add the line: sleep 5  http://www.antony-neu.com/2013/03/12/autostarting-a-browser-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with sh script !!! :)

Comment: your welcome. I have posted as answer, please accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add small delay before midori starts, which would be less reliable than ip checking. See section 3 on this link.
     http://www.antony-neu.com/2013/03/12/autostarting-a-browser-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Follow the steps and inside the bash script above the line that calls midori add a sleep period:

```
sleep 5
```